# WPF / prism navigation : Cannot create navigation target BView

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, containers, prism

In a wpf/mvvm/prism application, I got a problem when I navigate from a view to another.

I put a breakpoint in the navigation function prepare/request, in the AViewModel:

```
    private void Model(object sender)
    {
        if (sender == null) return;
        var file = ((RawImage)sender).FullName;
        var navParams = new NavigationParameters { { "filein", file } };
        var uri = new Uri(typeof(BView).Name + navParams, UriKind.Relative);
        _regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.TabRegion, uri, nr =>
        {
            var error = nr.Error;
            var result = nr.Result;
        }); //breakpoint here
    }
```

ne.Error: Cannot create navigation target 'BView'

In the module , I have registered the types:

```
    protected override void RegisterTypes()
    {
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<AView>();
        Container.RegisterType<IAViewModel, AViewModel>();
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<BView>();
        Container.RegisterType<IBViewModel, BViewModel>();
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<CView>();
        Container.RegisterType<ICViewModel, CViewModel>();
    }
```

When I ask to navigate to CView, it works but not BView.
Each view has its interface and viewmodel in its own folder.

What might be the problem ?
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to investigate more and do a view injection from InitializeModule() (of the module):

```
        var region = RegionManager.Regions[RegionNames.TabRegion];
        var view = Container.Resolve<BView>();
        region.Add(view);
        region.Activate(view);
```

Which led to a more readable message:

Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException' in Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll

Additional information: Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "Some.Namespace.BView", name = "(none)".

Exception occurred while: while resolving.

Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The type BViewModel has multiple constructors of length 1. Unable to disambiguate.

And by making sure I have only one viewmodel constructor with one argument:

```
    public BViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        _regionManager = regionManager;
        Initialize();
    }
```

I was finally able to go further.